# Site Error File Does Not Exist

Tags: web, performance

I used http://site-perf.com/ to test the speed of my site (http://sweatingthebigstuff.com) and it shows one file that gives a 404 error. That file does not exist (hence the error), but how do I found out how to fix it? I don't know where it is being called (definitely not in the code).

The file in question is:

sweatingthebigstuff.com/wp-content/themes/WillTech_5_3_2010/lib/images/icon-rss.gif

I assume that I used to have a file but since deleted it. It was in a widget and it is now pointing to a png file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> It was in a widget and it is now pointing to a png file.

There is a reference to it somewhere - in a forgotten HTML file, in a style sheet.... The easiest might be doing a full-text search for your whole (local) Wordpress directory for `icon-rss.gif`.

If that doesn't turn up anything - it should, though! - try using a downloader like GetLeft to fetch a full HTML copy of your site, and do a full text search on that. That should at least show you which page the offending line is on.

Comment: How do I do a full text search in the whole directory?

Comment: I found it:

.menu .rss a, .menu .rss a:hover{padding-right:16px; background:url('lib/images/rss-icon.gif') 100% 50% no-repeat; border:none}

What should I change it to or how can I modify it to not give an error. I added a png file by the same name and changed the gif to png, but got no good result.

Comment: @Daniel well, if the server is giving a 404, the file can't be there, can it? Do you need that icon?

Comment: I definitely don't need it, I don't even know what it is! But how much of the code can I delete?

Comment: @Daniel that is impossible to answer without knowing the project. Try removing the file reference only.